# Javers ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID when using 2 databases

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javers

I have this exception "ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID" when I store data in Postgres (using JPA Lazy Load) and I store javers in MongoDB

Spring Boot: 1.4.0.RELEASE

Sprig Data JPA: 1.4.0.RELEASE

Javers: 2.3.0

I debugged and saw that ID is null if object is a lazy object:
org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityType:88 "Object cdoId = getIdProperty().get(instance);"

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you commit an object to JaVers, its previous version is loaded from JaversRepository and compared with the current version (that version you have just passed to commit() method).
In this case JaVers finds the previous version using `GlobalId` query so TypeName + entity ID.
That's why ID can't be null for Entities.

There are two possibilities:

1. If null ID is normal in this class (according to your domain model) you should map it as [ValueObject](http://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#value-object) in JaVers.
2. If you are using Hibernate, there is common problem with lazy loading proxies. For certain queries, Hibernate doesn't return your real domain objects but dynamic proxy objects which are essentially empty (hence null ID). This technique maybe looks smart but makes your objects garbage until they are initialized by Hibernate. 
   JaVers provides [HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook](http://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#hibernate-unproxy-hook) which does the cleaning: initializing and un-proxying of your domain objects.

   JaversBuilder.javers().withObjectAccessHook(
   new HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook()).build()

This hook is enabled by default in `javers-spring-boot-starter-sql` but not in `javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo`. If you are using Mongo starter, create a JaVers bean on your own, with the hook enabled, see [JaversMongoAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo/src/main/java/org/javers/spring/boot/mongo/JaversMongoAutoConfiguration.java).

Comment: @BartekWalacik oh, just realized that you're the creator of Javers :-) Great Job!!! very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have my tables with inheritance in Spring boot; just to reuse primary key Id which is a Long type. When I try to test my objects to compare, it says the ID is null even though I set them myself. What could be the issue? Note: Thank you for the beautiful library!

Comment: "If you are using Hibernate". Does this mean that such an _unproxy_ mechanism is not typically required when using EclipseLink?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making my own access hook and added to the to the Javers with

> .withObjectAccessHook(new EntityAccessHook()).build()

```
public class EntityAccessHook<T> extends HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook<T> {

  @Override
  public Optional<ObjectAccessProxy<T>> createAccessor(T entity) {
    Optional<ObjectAccessProxy<T>> accessProxy = super.createAccessor(entity);
    if (accessProxy.isEmpty() && entity instanceof AbstractUuidEntity) {
      return fromEntityInitializer((AbstractUuidEntity) entity);
    }
    return accessProxy;
  }

  private Optional<ObjectAccessProxy<T>> fromEntityInitializer(
      AbstractUuidEntity abstractUuidEntity) {
    return Optional.of(
        new ObjectAccessProxy(
            () -> abstractUuidEntity,
            abstractUuidEntity.getClass(),
            abstractUuidEntity.getId() == null ? UUID.randomUUID() : abstractUuidEntity.getId()));
  }
}
```