# How to compare hibernate BO objects using Javers

Tags: java, javers

My requirement is that For application audit purposes i want to compare two BO objects and return a obj diff as a Json string to store details into audit table.To compare objects  i have chosen [Javers](http://javers.org/). in my case i have implemented a hibernate interceptor that will monitor the BO actions.That part works fine.But when try to compare BO objects with  Javers throw me a error called

```
ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID: Found Entity instance 'com.myproject.runtime.bo.Result_$$_jvstc5f_5' with null idProperty 'resultid'
```

**Here is my sample hibernate Result class**

```
class Result {

    @id //javax.persistence.Id
    resultid;
    name;
    etc ...
    }
```

**Obj comparison code snippet**

```
public static <B> String compareObjDiff(final B oldBo, final B newBo) {

        Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();

        Diff diff = javers.compare(oldBo, newBo);
        return javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff);
    }
```

Please let me know how can i compare hibernate BO objects using javers.also is it possible to ignore `@id` property?

*Note:Bo object can contains `null` values in runtime.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is Hibernate BO object.
If you mean domain objects (entities being persisted by Hibernate) -- the answer is in this question [Javers ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID when using 2 databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671954/javers-entity-instance-with-null-id-when-using-2-databases)